# Can I use ::before content to make a div a clickable link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

I'm working on some custom styling of a Wordpress site and there's a particular DIV that I'd like to make clickable rather than using the content that is in it.  Due to the page-builder the site is using, I'm finding it difficult and before I go and create an entire bit of custom HTML content, I want to know if I can modify the module via CSS or JS so that the site owner can still modify content.

Eg.

```css
.container {
 width: 100%;
  height:400px;
}

.container .module-content {
 display: block;
  height:150px;
  bottom:0;
  position: absolute;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 transition: ease .5s;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.container:hover .module-content {
 display: block;
  height:250px;
 overflow:visible;
}

.container .module-content .module-title {
 display: block;
 font-size:30px;
  height:100px;
 padding:50px 25px 0;
  margin:0;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(66,114,184,0) 0%, rgba(66,114,184,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(66,114,184,0) 0%,rgba(66,114,184,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(66,114,184,0) 0%,rgba(66,114,184,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#004272b8', endColorstr='#4272b8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
} 

.container .module-content .module-title a {
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  }

.container .module-content .module-description {
 background-color:#4272b8;
 height: 50px;
  padding:25px;
  margin:0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><!-- this is a 600x400 pixel box with an image for a background -->
      <div class="module-content"><!-- this is a 100px height div positioned absolutely and at the bottom with overflow hidden, when the container is hovered, the overflow becomes visible and height is 150px -->
        <div class="module-title"><h2><a href="/about/">About</a></h2></div><!-- this heading is the current link and is always visible -->
        <div class="module-description"><p>text</p></div><!-- this text is only visible when the container is hovered -->
      </div>
     </div>
```

As you'll see in the image below, I can only edit the heading text (with or without link), paragraph text and the container background.
The positioning of the content is done by CSS overrides.

[image]

I thought maybe I could just make the H2 `<a href></a>` a block so it covered the whole container, but it stuffs up the positioning of the "About" text (it moves it to the top, and I want it to appear at the bottom).

So I thought maybe I could use a psuedo like ::before or ::after with `content` to make the container DIV a clickable link...

Is this possible?  If not, how else could I achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Pseudo elements are not a part of the DOM, and they are not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

If I'm not wrong you cannot give a links for pseudo classes

> If not, how else could I achieve what I'm after?

For me the easy way (but maybe not the best) will be making the area for h2 link bigger like here:

https://jsfiddle.net/9j516L2g/6/

```
.clickable-area {
   display: inline-block;     
   position: relative;    
   z-index: 1;     
   padding-bottom: 20px;     
   margin-bottom: -20px; 
}
```

- display: inline-block is for setting margins
- position has to be relative
- z-index is for keeping clickable area on top (**remember about it if you are using somewhere other z-indexes**)
- Padding increases the area that can be clicked
- Negative margin is something that helps to not destroy surronding text

Example above will give 20px more at clickable area - you can do the same with left and right, so maybe it will be good solution for you.

Let me know if it's ok for you.